# What is the significance of the phase angle?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-state, quantum-phase-estimation, quantum-circuit

I've the following circuit which gives an output of `1` with a phase angle of `3π/4`. When we measure the circuit all we get is the state `1` (On actual QC, it's 90% of the time `1`). Is the information about the phase angle lost by measuring the state? Could the phase angle also be part of the output?

[image: Circuit]

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[1];
creg c[1];

u(pi/2,pi/2,0) q[0];
h q[0];
u(pi/2,pi/2,pi/2) q[0];
measure q[0] -> c[0];
```

Comment: As you said, the state that you have is $|\psi \rangle = e^{i 3\pi/4} |1\rangle$. This state is indistinguishable from the state $|\psi \rangle = |1\rangle$. States that are identical up to a global/overall phase are indistinguishable from each other.

Comment: This depends on if the phase is global or relative. Here's some more discussions about this : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257824/global-and-relative-phases-of-kets-in-qm , https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/401523/global-phases-and-indistinguishable-quantum-states-mathematical-understanding, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5125/what-is-the-difference-between-a-relative-phase-and-a-global-phase-in-particula, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12448/understanding-global-phase

Answer (score 1):

When we make a measurement we project the state of the qubit to the z-basis (i.e 0 or 1) so in general it is not possible to measure a global phase.

That said, Measuring such global phases is an important subroutine in many quantum algorithms such as Shor's algorithm.

This can be done using the **Quantum phase estimation algorithm**.
For details, check https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/quantum-phase-estimation.html
and the following chapter on Shor's algorithm.
The idea is roughly that of performing an interference experiment.